# How to normalize the response API using Normalizr?

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalization

I'm making a ReactJs Application using API from the back-end. I did it, but my solution to find the data to display on the app make it slowly.

Ex: I want to get {id, name, color} from the response API I must do like this.

```js
  if (meId && list.HasCalendar && list.Calendar && list.Calendar !== {}) {
    Object.keys(list.Calendar).forEach((key) => {
      const newCalendar = {
        bgColor: list.HasCalendar[meId].items[key].data.backgroundColor,
        color: list.HasCalendar[meId].items[key].data.colorId,
        id: key,
        name: list.Calendar[key].data.name
      };
      array.push(newCalendar);
    });
  }
```

`array` is used to display. I have some API must using 3 loops to find the data. I researched the performance problem and know that I can normalize responses to get data faster. I tried `Normailizr` but I still don't know how to make a schema from my response API.

This is my sample code: https://codesandbox.io/s/normalizr-gqiit

Can you show me how to deal with this response API? Thanks!